# Auth info fo go-netbox client

Tags: go, netbox

How to work with go-netbox client

Hi, i want to send data to netbox using go-netbox client.

```
    client := netbox.NewNetboxWithAPIKey("netbox.example.org", "<api-token>")

    ipaddress := "192.168.0.100"
    ipAddress := &models.IPAddress{
        Address:    &ipaddress, 
        Description: "Example IP Address",
    }

    createdIPAddress, err := client.Ipam.IpamIPAddressesCreate(ipAddress, ?)
```

What i need to pass to authInfo ?

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass `nil` to it.

When the client is created with an API key, this API key will be used to issue requests. So it's OK to pass `nil` to the func. See [the source code](https://github.com/netbox-community/go-netbox/blob/3237c9d5509bfd63491ad2635b6bd6f0ed5313bb/netbox/netbox.go#L42) where a default `runtime.ClientAuthInfoWriter` is created.

If the client is created without feeding the API key and you need to provide a `runtime.ClientAuthInfoWriter` to a func, you can create one like this:

```golang
import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/go-openapi/runtime/client"
)

var apiKeyAuth = runtime.APIKeyAuth("Authorization", "header", fmt.Sprintf("Token %v", apiToken))
```

References:

1. [Authenticating to the API](https://docs.netbox.dev/en/stable/integrations/rest-api/#authenticating-to-the-api):

   > An authentication token is attached to a request by setting the `Authorization` header to the string `Token` followed by a space and the user's token
2. [github.com/go-openapi/runtime/client](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-openapi/runtime/client): see the list of funcs that return a `runtime.ClientAuthInfoWriter`.